# Binding Data to database in angular 2

Tags: sql-server, angular2-forms, angular2-services

So what i am facing is i can not save my data to database from the drop-down list which is the static list created in html. I have all the services like integration services and client services but i can not save it to the database.

This is HTML

```
 <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
      <legend class="scheduler-border">
        Billing Information (Required)</legend>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-5">


            <select name="SampleList" (change)="item.SampleList" class="form-control form-white input-lg" data-search="true">
              <option>Choose</option>
              <option value="Patient Bill">Patient Bill</option>
              <option value="Client Bill">Client Bill</option>
              <option value="Insurance Bill">Insurance Bill</option>
            </select>
          </div>

        </div>
      </fieldset>
```

component.ts :

```
  public SampleList = [];
    this.SampleList = accessionservice.GetSampleList();
   this._clientService
          .SaveAccessionSample(tData.Sample, this.accessionNo)
          .subscribe(d => {
            console.log(d);
          });


  this._clientService
          .GetPatientSampleAccessionId(this.accessionNo)
          .subscribe(Dc => {
            var data = Dc.ResultSets[0];
            data.forEach(element => {
              this.SampleList.forEach(data => {
                if (data.Sample === element.Sample) {
                  data.IsChecked = true;
                }
              });
            });
          });
```

earlier the data was saved from check boxes now i had to make it saved from drop-down and i am quite new to angular that's why facing some problem.
If you do not get my question than please let me know in the comment section but please do the reply.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should try attaching `[(ngModel)]` to your select and have `(ngModelChange)` tied to your function which will take care of making your service call for saving the info.

Ex:

```
       <select class="form-control" 
           id="selInfoInput" 
           [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory" 
           (ngModelChange)="onCategoryChange(selectedCategory)"> ....</select>
```

onCategoryChange is the method defined in your component class.